# Powershell-Create folder inside a sub folder that is buried deep down and full path is not known

Tags: powershell

I want to create a folder inside a sub folder that is buried deep down. I don't know the full path but I know the folder name where I want to create this new directory.

`Get Child-Item` give me the full path of the desired folder but I can't get it working with New-Item command.

[image]

In the following snippet, I want to create new directory inside `TempFolder` and I want to achieve this in one line statement.

[image]

Comment: "*it don't work with New-Item command*" tells us absolutely nothing about the issue. I assure you they work together, so provide some details on what actually happens and we might be able to help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Does the full path exceed 260 characters?

Comment: @DougMaurer I have added the screenshot of the error. FYI, I get another error "New-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Get-ChildItem'." when I remove the first "-Path"

Comment: @Thomas, No it is less than 260.

Comment: you need to add the directory in a variable $a then $a.fullname is your path "c:\temp\foldera\folderb\folderc  after on variable $a.fullname you can create new directory see my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

```
$a=Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp\foldera\folderb -Recurse |? {$_.BaseName -eq "folderc"}
New-Item -Path $a.FullName -Name "folderd" -ItemType "directory"
```

Answer (score 2):

To incorporate your `Get-ChildItem` command inline, you'll need to enclose it in parenthesis.

```
New-Item -Path (Get-ChildItem -Path c:\testTemp -Recurse | Where-Object BaseName -eq "TempFolder") -Name "newDirTest" -ItemType "Directory"
```

Comment: Thanks @Doug. My bad, I tried with curly brace but never thought of using round bracket.